# cuda to llvm bitcode conversion

Tags: cuda, llvm, gpu

I want to convert CUDA code to llvm bitcode so I can instrument it. I have tried gpuocelot, which compile ptx into CPU executable code. Nevertheless, I couldn't get llvm bitcode from it so I can't instrument it. There have been activities trying to get CUDA supported in llvm. Can anyone provide a robust solution to convert CUDA to workable llvm bitcode? Thanks.

Comment: It seems gpuocelot is implemented using LLVM, so an intermediate step there should be parsing the ptx into LLVM IR. What have you tried to do to get it, and how did it fail?

Comment: @Oak:gpuocelot starts from .o from nvcc and outputs a .out file for execution. I don't know how to get a bitcode .bc file for llvm instrumentation. Any suggestion?

Comment: As gpucelot is open source you can get its sources, modify it to dump the LLVM IR after it parses it, then run it on your inputs. Every LLVM element has a `dump()` method which dumps the IR (in textual format, but that's easily converted to bitcode) to stdout, for example, and I'm sure there are more refined ways.

Answer (score 1):

NVIDIA's nvcc is actually using LLVM IR as one of its steps. They might have changed it a little bit - I haven't seen the details. They have explained it under:

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-llvm-compiler

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Clang to compile CUDA (mixed-mode) to LLVM IR now. Check [this page](http://llvm.org/docs/CompileCudaWithLLVM.html) out. Note that this support is still experimental. Feel free to report bugs to the LLVM community.